# SSRS report built in VS need to export to 3 separate Excel tabs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have 3 datasets and 3 tablix's or tables in an SSRS report and each has a different page name and the first two have a page break set to End. However, I only get two worksheets generated and the second two are combined into one worksheet.

I have another report that works perfectly and it seems to be set up exactly the same.

Comment: What if you "Add a page break after" for each table under table properties?

Comment: For some reason that hasn't worked other than the first table. What I did was to create a table header for the third table, instead of a text box that wasn't attached to the table and then set that table to page break before and that seemed to work. Odd but at least it's working. Thank you for your helpl.